# duplicate posts when trying to update a post using the wp_insert_post.

Tags: posts, wp-insert-post

On an empty wordpress database, I insert one sample post using the wp_insert_post.

Since it's an empty database, the first post I add ends up with id 1. 
And I check that in the wp_posts, everything looks right ( well for some reason post_name is blank but I do not want to focus on that now ).

The question is but when I want to update that post ( again using the wp_insert_post), instead of updating the early record, I end up getting post id 2!

If you ask how I update the record with the wp_insert_post, I simply set the ID to 1 when I build my $data array for the wp_insert_post.

The codex say that when you supply the 'ID' array element to the wp_insert_post's $data array, it simply updates that post with that ID.

Well, in my cases, It does not.

I end up getting the post id 2.
Post ID 2's author goes as 0  (post id's author was 1 ), and post id 2's post_name is 1-revision  (  post id 1s post_name was blank as I said above)

Any idea of why this could be happening?

Or should I simply forget the idea of using wp_insert_post for post updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should insert posts with [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) and update posts with [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).  `wp_update_post` will add a revision to the database and update the published/draft post data.

Comment: Thank you. But, I think you meant "`wp_insert_post` will add a revision..." NOT `wp_update_post`.

Comment: No I pull that back. you are right, wp_update_post also does the same thing, it too ads a revision. For a moment, I had thought only wp_insert does that revision thing. But all updates be it thru wp_insert_post or wp_update_post adds the revision post. And there is only one way to get rid of that, which is thru wp-config.php